# RegNotifyChangeKeyValue

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for some example code to monitor changes made to the registry. I see that there is a `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` api, but I am having some trouble implementing it.

There is a C# example at this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC

But am having trouble converting it to vb.net.

Can someone point me into the right direction for some VB.NET examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the code from http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.regnotifychangekeyvalue

Use the c# to VB.net converters from
http://converter.telerik.com/